# How to extract signatures of signed packages in Java?

Tags: android

```
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("pkgname", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
Signature[] sig = info.signatures;
String sigstring = new String(sig[0].toChars());
System.out.println(sigstring);`
```

I wrote the following scriptlet to extract the signature but it does not work.

I found this on the net.

I get a compilation error as "the method getPackageManager() is undefined for this class"

I also tried using context class but doesnt help.

Comment: Where do you put this code (and please indent properly)

Answer (score 1):

The method `getPackageManager()` belongs to the [android.content.Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) class and is therefore present in all subclasses.

If the code you have posted does not work you have implemented it most likely not in an Activity or Service. Both derive from Context and therefore have this method.